# Is there a way to make a cube spin consistently?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's my code

```
int rotY = 0;
int rotDecider = 0;

void Update()
{
  if (rotDecider == 7) { //The threshold for rotating 1 unit
    //This creates a sort of delay
    rotDecider = 0; //Reset rotDecider
    rotY++; //Increase rotation by one unit
    gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, rotY, 0); //Apply to the Y axis
  } else {
    rotDecider++;
  }

}
```

When I execute this, the code spins, but it stops every once in a while. (While I'm here, are placing brackets on the same line of a statement bad?)

Comment: In 8 frames, 7 are saying your GameObject: *don't do anything*. So it's not strange that it "stops once in a while", even that you are not using `Time.deltaTime` to have time consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no guarantee `Update()` is called at any sort of consistent rate. Instead,  use [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) to figure out the rotation rate.

```
void Update()
{
  gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, 5 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}
```